# Sub Query with case statement

Tags: case-statement

```
SELECT
A.MARKETING_PLAN,
A.TERM,
A.TIER
CASE WHEN A.TERM<=60 THEN 'ST' ELSE 'LT' end as TERM_2
FROM ABC A;
```

I want to write the following case statement by using TERM_2 field(has 2 subset:LT and ST).

**CASE WHEN TERM_2=LT and TIER=5 THEN 5.49 ELSE 'NULL' END AS BU**

I can not use the above case statement as TERM_2 is just created.
I think I need to use sub query and I tried many ways but it does not work.
Please look at my code and help me solve the issue.
Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Because `a.bu` depends on value of `a.term_2` and `a.tier`, it indirectly depends on `a.term` field. So you simply need to check whether `a.term` is greater than 60 (`a.term_2` equals to `LT` if `a.term` is greater than 60).

```
SELECT
  a.marketing_plan,
  a.term,
  a.tier,
  CASE WHEN a.term<=60 THEN 'ST' ELSE 'LT' END AS term_2,
  CASE WHEN a.term>60 AND a.tier=5 THEN 5.49 ELSE NULL END AS bu
FROM ABC a;
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.